# SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000 : hibernate with concurrence connection

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I've currently two server who are running a same application, this morning they tried to save at the same time an instance of an object 'Rackstatus'.

The result was :

> 10:23:37,781 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter]
>   (XXXX) SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
>   10:23:37,783 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter]
>   (XXXX) Duplicate entry '114464' for key
>   'PRIMARY' 10:23:37,784 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener]
>   (XXXX) Could not synchronize database state with
>   session: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could
>   not execute JDBC batch update

my save code :

```
public void Save(RackStatus stData)  {
        Session session = null;
        session = super.getSession("BANK");
        //Create new instance
        Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
        // execute save
        session.save(stData);
        // do commit
        trans.commit();
}
```

And finally hibernate definition :

```
<id name="id" type="int">
    <column name="id" />
     <generator class="assigned"/> 
</id>
```

Any idea ? Thanks.